# Generating very large random numbers java

Tags: java, random, biginteger, largenumber

How can we generate very large random number in java? I am talking something like 10000 digits? I know we have to use BigInteger but how can we do this? What is the most efficent way of doing something like this? Please provide a small example. Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, one way is to go to [Random.org](http://www.random.org/) and download a one of the binary random files.  The files are generated from atmospheric noise, so it's very random.  I used it for Zobrist keys in my chess engine.

Alternatively you could go

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(256, new Random());
```

which will give you what you want.  In this example, a BigInteger consisting of 256 bits.

Comment: +1. It was four constructors down in the documentation, I didn't see it :D.

Answer (score 9):

Combine [`Random.nextBytes(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes(byte[])) with [`BigInteger(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(byte[])).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
class Test{
    public static void main(String[]_){

        int n = 16;

        Random r = new Random();
        byte[] b = new byte[n];
        r.nextBytes(b);
        BigInteger i = new BigInteger(b);

        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how this works? i'm more or less confused on the bytes part.. thanks

Comment: You allocate an array of bytes, nextBytes fills it with random values, and then the BigInteger is initialized as the binary number defined by that sequence of bytes. But I think Jaco's solution is more concise.

Answer (score -3):

You can just type:

`int number = (int)(Math.random() * 100);`

Also, you can generate even bigger numbers if you change the multiplier:

`int number = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);`

P.S. You don't need to import a class.

Comment: The question asks for numbers with 10000 digits. This answer does not even come close.

Comment: 1000 digits won't fit into variable of int type. Multiplying random value by some constant makes it not random.

Comment: Although this answer might work for small numbers, the question is clear that it is for very large (much bigger than an int) numbers.  So this is not a valid answer.