# What variable type can I use to hold huge numbers (30+ digits) in java?

Tags: java, biginteger, bigdecimal

Is there a really large variable type I can use in Java to store huge numbers (up to around forty digits)?

`long`'s maximum value is 9223372036854775807, which is 19 digits -- not nearly large enough.

I'm trying to create a calculator that can handle large numbers, because most nowadays can only hold an insufficient 10 digits or so, and I want want accurate calculations with numbers of a much larger magnitude

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers. I can use `BigInteger` for big integers, the only limit being the computer's memory (should be sufficient). For decimals, I'll use `float` ^e, as @WebDaldo suggested, or `BigDecimal` (similar to BigInteger), as @kocko suggested.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

```
BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger("637824629384623845238423545642384"); 
BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger("3039768898793547264523745379249934"); 

BigInteger bigSum = bi1.add(bi2);
        
BigInteger bigProduct = bi1.multiply(bi2);
       
System.out.println("Sum : " + bigSum);
System.out.println("Product : " + bigProduct);
```

Output:

> Sum : 3677593528178171109762168924892318
>
> Product : 1938839471287900434078965247064711159607977007048190357000119602656

I should mention [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which is excellent for amount calculations compare to *double*.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("123234545.4767");
BigDecimal displayVal = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);

NumberFormat usdFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);        
System.out.println(usdFormat.format(displayVal.doubleValue()));
```

Output:

> $123,234,545.48

Comment: do you know what the largest value of `BigInteger` is?

Comment: @Jon: Probably somewhere above 2^1000000.  Depends on how much memory you have, really.

Comment: @Jon It's `(2^32)^(2^31-1)`.

Comment: can i use; `BigInteger testData = Math.random() * LIMIT  + 1;`  ??

Comment: @rootTraveller You must understand the differences among different types, primitives vs objects, etc. If you want to randomize, look at these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244691/generating-very-large-random-numbers-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290057/how-to-generate-a-random-biginteger-value-in-java

Answer (score 12):

You can try using the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class for operations with really huge integer numbers.

For operations with floating numbers, Java provides the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class, which can be useful, as well.

Answer (score 4):

For calculations with exponents, like you would use in a calculator, you should use `BigDecimal`. The problem with `BigInteger` is that it only handles integers (no fractional numbers) and that for really big numbers like 10^100 it stores all the zeros, using a lot of memory, instead of using a format based on scientific notation.

You could alternatively use the floating point number type `double`, which gives you a large range of values, low memory usage and fast operations.  But because of rounding issues and limited precision (around 16 decimal digits), I wouldn't recommend using it unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use float ^e

so you could have

```
0.55342663552772737682136182736127836782163 * 10^e
```

Calculators are mostly use that, too.

Comment: A float has only about 8 decimal digits of precision. You probably should avoid using it.

Comment: (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)
The floating-point types are float and double, which are conceptually associated with the single-precision 32-bit and double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values and operations as specified in IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic, ANSI/IEEE Standard 754-1985 (IEEE, New York).

Comment: You do know that 32 bits means that only 23 are used for the mantissa? And that with 23 bits you can only represent numbers with 7-8 digits, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is for all bigger numbers above 15 since using int blows it. You may want to find the factorial of 50 or 100 0r 500.

```
// Recursive version of the Fat factorial for bigger numbers ex: Factorial of 500     
BigInteger fatFactorial(int b) {
    if (BigInteger.ONE.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(b))
        || BigInteger.ZERO.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(b))) {
            return BigInteger.ONE;
    } else {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(b).multiply(fatFactorial(b - 1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Comment: This is for all bigger numbers above 15 since using int blows it. You may want to find the factorial of 50 or 100 0r 500. This works.

Comment: public class Factorial {
 BigInteger fatFactorial(int b) {
  if (BigInteger.ONE.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(b))
    || BigInteger.ZERO.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(b))) {
   return BigInteger.ONE;
  } else {
   return BigInteger.valueOf(b).multiply(fatFactorial(b - 1));
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Factorial fac = new Factorial();
  System.out.println("Fat Numbers Fact of " + 500 + " = "
    + fac.fatFactorial(500));
 }
}

Comment: No, no! Edit it into your answer. The explanation is not for me, it is for the googlers of the future (and for the java beginners).

Comment: No, you don't need to include the whole class, it doesn't make things more clear. Your original code snippet is enough, but give an explanation with that.

Comment: added it in the comment.