# C# Biginteger for huge number of bits

Tags: c#, arrays, bigdata, biginteger

I would like to know if there is any efficient way to store a big number using C#. I would like to create number consisting of 960 bytes but `BigInteger` can't hold it. I would be grateful for any advice.

UPDATE: I am using random byte generator to fill up array needed for constructor of `BigInteger`. For 960 byte array i `BigInteger` is returning a negative number.

Comment: why can't `BigInteger` hold it? It should be able to hold as much data as you have memory available...

Comment: What error do you get ? How are you declaring it ? Can you show some sample.

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444337/what-variable-type-can-i-use-to-hold-huge-numbers-30-digits-in-java

Comment: That's a big number.  Are you cataloging grains of sand?

Comment: This question need more details.  It also needs to be more directed.  What problems are you experiencing?  Show your code.

Comment: i edit the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code you are referencing.

Comment: if the number is negative, it's not because it is too big for `BigInteger` - it's because your number is actually a negative value.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: more like atoms in the known universe. 960 bytes is about 2311 decimal digits. The number of atoms in the known universe is estimated at between 10^80 and 10^85. <g>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var arr = new byte[960];

    for (int i = 0; i != arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = byte.MaxValue;
    }

    var big = new BigInteger(arr);
}
```

is working pretty fine and the result is `-1` because the representation of the number is in the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). That means a number with just `1`s in binary always resolves to -1 as you can see in the article.

---

if you add one Length more and set the **last** element of the array to zero you should get a positive number which represents your binary number (this one byte will not hurt you):

```
var arr = new byte[961];
arr[arr.Length-1] = 0;
var big2 = new BigInteger(arr);
```

but then you really should be sure in what format your binary number is and what `BigInteger` is "reading"

Comment: thanks, indeed it is working ok. I just thought i am getting overflow.

Comment: on the first five seconds i was also suprised but then i realized the complement. i will also add a solution

Comment: to sum up. If my BigInteger has a negative sign that means my 960 byte representing a negative number right?

Comment: @Dago yes. When the MSB (most significant bit) is 1 then your number is negative. That means doing (this sets the MSB to 1): `arr[arr.Length - 1] |= 0b1000 0000` will result always in a negative number.