# Generate random number of n digits or more

Tags: java, random, biginteger

I saw many examples to generate random numbers in a specific range [min-max], but i need java code that generates random numbers of n digits or more, so in this case `min= 10000000` and `no max`.

Note - I am using `BigInteger`

Comment: "no max" assuming you are using `int` or `long`, there is a max: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils may help you here, you can create String that contains only digits with length you need.

Comment: i am using BigInteger

Comment: Use `long random = new Random().nextLong() + n*10;`

Comment: Even if you're using `BigInteger`, you must have a practical limitation on the number you want to generate. I mean, you could generate a number with as many digits as your heap will allow... but what are you going to do with that?

Comment: Would suggest using strings in case the use case is well served as pointer by Andy in comments, there has to be a purpose.

Comment: @Andy i need it for a cryptography algorithm

Comment: As Andy has pointed out, however, you're going to have to cap it somehow or you'll reach system limitations.

Comment: I know it’s not what you asked, but I want to mention anyway: for cryptography you will probably want to look into SecureRandom (used the right way it can generate digit strings long enough for your cryptographical strength requirements).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8244798/1746118 does this help/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the constructor `BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)` to generate positive random numbers with N bits.

As you want to have a minimum, you can add that as an offset to the generated numbers:

```
Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
BigInteger base = BigInteger.valueOf(10000000); // min
int randomBits = 50; // set as many bits as you fancy

BigInteger rnd = base.add(new BigInteger(randomBits, random));
```

Answer (score 1):

`BigInteger` accepts a decimal String in one of its constructors.  Generate individual digits and append them to a String.  When you have enough digits in your String, create your `BigInteger` from the String.  You may want to constrain the first digit to be in [1 .. 9] to avoid leading zeros, depending on your exact requirement.